# OpenCV displays 'None' for a large number of images

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to run a pre-trained pose detection model on a new dataset.

When I pass a single image to the model, I get the correct results.
Although, when I apply a for loop for multiple images present in a folder(as shown below), openCV even fails to load half of the images.

Keep in mind I am running this code on Intel i3 dual core laptop.

```
import os 
import cv2
DIR="C:\\Name_of_Folder\\"
for i in os.listdir(DIR):
    image=cv2.imread(i)
    print(image,i)
```

Output:
None frame_000000.jpg
None frame_000001.jpg
None frame_000002.jpg
None frame_000003.jpg

Answer (score 4):

`os.listdir()` does not return absolute file paths, but only the file names.

```
import os
import cv2
DIR="C:\\Name_of_Folder\\"
for i in os.listdir(DIR):
    image=cv2.imread(os.path.join(DIR, i))
    print(image,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The path you're trying to use to read image is wrong. You have to use:

```
import cv2
import os
DIR="C:\\Name_of_Folder\\"
for i in os.listdir(DIR):
  image=cv2.imread(os.path.join(DIR,i))
  print(image,i)
```